# zsh: command not found: mkfs on macOS

Tags: macos, command

Hi i entered it in terminal macOS

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=img.1440 bs=1k count=1440
mkfs img.1440
```

And got this error

```
zsh: command not found: mkfs
```

Answer (score 1):

`mkfs` is a Linux command, but if you have Homebrew installed, you can install `e2fsprogs`:

```
brew install e2fsprogs
```

Then run `mkfs.ext3`:

```
$(brew --prefix e2fsprogs)/sbin/mkfs.ext3 img.1440
```

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: I followed your suggestion and got this
`Filesystem too small for a journal
Creating filesystem with 1440 1k blocks and 176 inodes

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done`
But this error still exist